# Octave: How to put in a Variable into a Filename for Fopen

Tags: variables, octave, filenames

I have a Variable which is part of the Name of my Textfile:

Test123_Variable.txt

Now I want to use the Function fopen to open the textfile, but since my Filename is dependent on the name of my variable I don't know how to make the right syntax:

This is obviously not working:
`filename = ("Test123_Variable.txt");`

How can I fix this?

Comment: The name of your variable? Why would your variable name change? That is not good practice. You should have fixed variable names. If you have many files to open, put their names into an array.

Comment: The Variable Name stays exactly the same, but the value behind the Variable changes constantly.

Comment: Ok, so then what is the problem? Why does `filename = ("Test123_Variable.txt");` not work? Maybe if you give an actual example, with code, of what you are trying to achieve, we can help you?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand right your purpose,

```
filename = ["Test123_" Variable ".txt"];
```

should do what you expect. Example:

```
>> Variable = "sample_1";
>> filename = ["Test123_" Variable ".txt"]
filename = Test123_sample_1.txt
```